# Set environment variables for rails app hosted in nginx/passenger

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, environment-variables

How do I set environment variables so that they are available to my rails app hosted inside nginx/passenger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a few different nginx including passenger_set_cgi_param, env and fast_cgi_param. Unfortunately none of these worked for me. In the end I exported them as bash variables in the startup script I was using to launch nginx.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, 'sudo env VAR=VALUE nginx' solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to replace your passenger_ruby with a wrapper script.

```
http {
    ...
    passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

to

```
http {
    ...
    passenger_ruby /path/to/passenger_ruby
```

passenger_ruby is a shell script with following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
export MY_ENV="value"
exec "/usr/bin/ruby" "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem which loads the env vars from a file of your choice.